# calculate the sum of diagonals in a matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

I need to calculate the sum of two diagonals in a matrix in C++, I already have a solution for that but I must be dumb because I cant understand what it is doing, so I would like to know if there is another version which I can understand. here is the code which does the job:

```
cout<<"Jepi rangun e  matrices"<<endl;  // pra bejme manipulim me matrice katrore ku rreshtat=kolonat
cin>>n;
cout<<"Tani jepi elementet e matrices"<<endl; // lexohet matrica

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
     for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        cin>>a[i][j];
}

d=0;
s=0; // ketu e keni kushtin si dhe mbledhjen per te dy diagonalet me dy variabla te ndryshme

for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
    {
        if(i==j)
            d=d+a[i][j];
        if(j==n-i+1 || i==n-j+1) 
            s=s+a[i][j];
    }
```

The part that is difficult to understand is

```
if(j==n-i+1 || i==n-j+1) 
    s=s+a[i][j];
```

Here is the entire code that I changed but it doesnt work for the secondary diagonal:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int d=0,s=0; // ketu e keni kushtin si dhe mbledhjen per te dy diagonalet me dy variabla te ndryshme
    int i,j,n;
    int a[5][5];

    cout<<"Jepi rangun e  matrices"<<endl;  // pra bejme manipulim me matrice katrore ku rreshtat=kolonat
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Tani jepi elementet e matrices"<<endl; // lexohet matrica

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
            cin>>a[i][j];
    }

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        {
            if(i==j) 
                d+=a[i][j]; //principal diagonal 
            if(i+j==n-1)
                s+=a[i][j];//secondary diagonal

        }
    }

    cout << d << endl;
    cout << s << endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question about any part this code?

Comment: @DrewDormann yeah this is the problem: 
if(j==n-i+1 || i==n-j+1)    s=s+a[i][j];

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It would be nice to have comments in English, but, the your code does (second loop):

```
browse all rows
  browse all cells
    if i == j (is in main diagonal):
        increase one sum
    if i == n - i + 1 (the other diagonal)
        increase the second sum
```

The much nicer and much more effective code (using `n`, instead of `n^2`) would be:

```
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++){
   d += a[i][i];  // main diagonal
   s += a[i][n-i-1]; // second diagonal (you'll maybe need to update index)
}
```

This goes straight trough the diagonals (both at the one loop!) and doesn't go trough other items.

**EDIT:**

Main diagonal has coordinates `{(1,1), (2,2), ..., (i,i)}` (therefor `i == j`).

Secondary diagonal has coordinates (in matrix 3x3): `{(1,3), (2,2),(3,1)}` which in general is: `{(1,n-1+1), (2, n-2+1), ... (i, n-i+1), .... (n,1)}`. But in C, arrays are indexed from 0, not 1 so you won't need that `+1` (probably).

All those items in secondary diagonal than has to fit condition: `i == n - j + 1` (again due to C's indexing from 0 `+1` changes to `-1` (`i=0,`, `n=3`, `j=2`, `j = n - i - 1`)).

You can achieve all this in one loop (code above).

Comment: @cyborg `n=5; i=0;` that would mean that second index `j=6;` which is out of boundaries (I assume `j=4` is correct in this case).

Answer (score 6):

```
int diag1=0;
int diag2=0;

for (i=0;i<n;i++)
 for (j=0;j<n;j++){

  if(i==j)  diag1+=a[i][j]; //principal diagonal 
  if(i+j==n-1) diag2+=a[i][j];//secondary diagonal
```

}

To understand this algorithm better you should paint a matrix on you notebook and number it's elements with their position in matrix,then apply the algorithm step by step.I'm 100% sure that you will understand

Comment: Yeah I painted the matrix but yet I got lost.. but now I understand it after I saw your code this was helpful: if(i+j=n-1)

Comment: Try to do what the computer does.Use n=3 and this values
a(1,1) a(1,2) a(1,3),
a(2,1) a(2,2) a(2,3), 
a(3,1) a(3,2) a(3,3) (change the a in a number)
Then go in for loop and note your i and j and then check the if's

Comment: I tried this in C++ and it didnt work for the secondary diagonal

Comment: well my algorithm use this for the for loop(i=0;i<n;i++).But for you for loop write this for the secondary diagonal  if(i+j==n+1)

Answer (score 4):

How about I try to explain this version? :D

There are 3 important parts of the code:

- inputing the matrix
- calculating major diagonal ( \ direction)
- calculating minor diagonal ( / direction)

And here they are, explained:

```
// input elements
for(i=1;i<=n;i++) // from left to right
{
    for(j=1;j<=n;j++) // from up to down
        cin>>a[i][j]; // input element at (i,j) position
}
```

Here, d and s contain the inter-values of major and minor diagonal respectively. At the end of 2 loops, they will contain the results

```
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
     for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
     {
        if(i==j)          // major diagonal - if coordinates are the same
           d=d+a[i][j];   // e.g. (1,1), (2,2)
        if(j==n-i+1 || i==n-j+1)  // coordinates of the minor diagonal - check
           s=s+a[i][j];           // e.g. n=3 (3,1) (2,2) ...
      }
```

Hope this helps.

Note that this code starts matrix coordinates at 1 instead of 0, so you will actually need to allocate `(n+1)x(n+1)` space for the matrix:

```
double a[n+1][n+1];
```

before using it.

Also, the code you gave is not most effective. It has `O(n^2)` complexity, while the task can be done in `O(n)` like so:

```
// matrix coordinates now start from 0
for (int i=0; i < n; ++i){
    d += a[i][i]; // major
    s += a[i][n-1-i]; // minor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int num[5][5]={0}; //decleration
int i=0,j=0,sum=0; 
for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        cin>>num[i][j];
    }                          //Taking Matrix input
}
        cout<<endl<<"The Matrix is "<<endl;
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            cout<<num[i][j]<<" ";
        }
            cout<<endl;               //Displaying the Matrix
    }                               
cout<<endl<<"The sum of diagonals of the matrix is "<<endl;
if(i==j) 
{
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            if (i==j)       //This loop works where i and j will be equal
            {
            sum=sum+num[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<sum;
}
else   //Some times the user creates 4 x 3 matrix or so than diagonals not match so. . . 
{
    cout<<"The sum is not Possible";
}
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest solution for this matrix. . . .!!

Answer (score 0):

you must use `i + j == n + 1` instead of `i + j == n - 1` for secondary diagonal i.e

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    for(j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if(i == j) 
            d += a[i][j]; //principal diagonal 
        if(i + j == n+1)
            s += a[i][j];//secondary diagonal

    }
}
```