# How to input numbers by keyboard in js matrices

Tags: javascript, matrix, input

I stuck with my program. I have to make a matrix and enter a value of every cell, then calculate the sum of the elements of the two main diagonals of the matrix. 
1st problem - I can't find solution how to make matrix with elements that I enter by keyboard.

```
<meta charset="windows-1251">
<script>
    //10. A real square matrix of size n x n. Calculate the sum of the elements of the two main diagonals of the matrix.
    var r,c; //r - rows, c - columns
    r = prompt('Enter the number of rows');
    c = prompt('Enter the number of columns');
    var mat = [];
        for (var i=0; i<r; i++){
            mat[i] = [];
        }
            for (var j=0; j<c; j++){
                mat[i][j]= prompt ('Enter a value for the cell ' + i + 'x' + j)

            }

    document.write(' <XMP> ');
    document.write('Matrix \t' + mat + '\r');
    document.write('</XMP>');

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there just missed by a brace !.It should've been like this

```
for (var i=0; i<r; i++){
  mat[i] = [];                     // A
  for (var j=0; j<c; j++){
    mat[i][j]= prompt ('Enter a value for the cell ' + i + 'x' + j); // B
  }
}
```

Inner loop will run for every single iteraion of outer loop (row) and populate every column in that row
To display array you should use `console.log()` (for debugging only) because if you print array along with other strings then it will get converted to string which is just its name loosing all other contents .To print array for the user or file in a readable form you need to use a loop again just remove line A and replace line B with whatever function u're using for writes passing `mat[i][j]` in earlier code

For diagonal sum you may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008505/calculate-the-sum-of-diagonals-in-a-matrix) useful it's a C++ question but it will also work for you case there is nothing c++ specific in there

Comment: Thats is it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a task.

```
<meta charset="windows-1251">
<script>
    //10.  A real square matrix of size n x n. Calculate the sum of the elements of the two main diagonals of the matrix.
    var r,c,d1,d2; //r - rows, c - columns, d1 - first diagonal, d2 - second diagonal
    d1 = 0;
    d2 = 0;
    r = prompt('Enter the number of rows');
    c = prompt('Enter the number of columns');
    var mat = [];
        for (var i=0; i<r; i++){
            mat[i] = [];
            for (var j=0; j<c; j++){
                mat[i][j]= prompt ('Enter a value for the cell ' + i + 'x' + j);
                    if (i == j){
                        d1 = +d1 + +mat[i][j];
                    }
                    if (i+j == +r-1){
                        d2 = +d2 + +mat[i][j];
                    }
            }
        }   
    document.write('Diagonal 1 = ' + d1 + "<br>" + 'Diagonal 2 = ' + d2 + "<br>");

</script>
```