# Go through all the major diagonals in matrix, including principal

Tags: algorithm, matrix

How do I go through all the diagonals in the matrix? There were similar questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008505/calculate-the-sum-of-diagonals-in-a-matrix/9008599#9008599) one, but they just calculate the sum. I need to perform certain operations going through all the diagonals, not just summing. To be clear, I need to traverse through it in way like in the picture:

[image: Explanation]

I've came up with this solution, but it is awful:

```
for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n && i + j < m; i++) {
            cout << matrix[i][i + j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < m && i + j < n; j++) {
            cout << matrix[j + i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

For the matrix n*m I first go through every diagonal right from the main one, and then left from the main one, but this solution seems ugly to me.

Comment: You need a first loop to iteratively find the starting point of each diagonal, and then an inner loop to follow each diagonal. Where are you blocked ?

Comment: @Damien with compressing it to just one loop with inner loop. I've came up with a solution which requires two loops, both with inner one, but it looks awful. I'll add it to the question

Comment: Note that for both loops, a `while` loop seems easier to control than a `for` loop

Comment: Your inner loops don't really traverse a diagonal. You'd have to increment both `i` and `j` for that.

Comment: Are you obliged to start with the main diagonal? If not, you can easily  obtain one inner loop only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simpler iteration at the cost of a modulo operation:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        cout << a[(i+j)%n][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a first loop to find the starting point of each diagonal,  and a second loop to follow the diagonal.

Here is a pseudo-code, assuming the point (0, 0) is the lower one.

```
(i_start, j_start) = (1, 0)
While (1)
    If (i_start, j_start) out of bound: break
    (i, j) = (i_start, j_start)
    While (1)
         If (i, j) out of bound: break
         Write matrix[i][j]
         i--, j++
    End while
    If (i_start not max) i_start++
    Else j_start++
End while
```